# Does Bigtable write operations to the log for every single operation or in batches?

Tags: bigtable

I was wondering how Google's Bigtable stays persistent. When a write operation comes in, the tablet server updates the in-memory "hashmap" and it is also written to a log file. This way, if the tablet server dies, a new tablet server can read all recent operations and be "equal" to the dead tablet.

This makes sense, but doesn't it slow down to write every operation to a log server rather than in batch (because it is written to a disk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take each of these questions in turn.

> Does Bigtable write operations to the log for every single operation or in batches?

Bigtable writes every single operation to the persistent log as they come in, not in batch. In other words, it's synchronous, rather than asynchronous: by the time the server responds to the client, the data was already written to a log (which is durable and replicated), not just to memory.

If a storage system only writes to memory, and writes out to a log in batches, it will lose data that was only in memory if the server were to crash after accepting some writes, but before it flushed them to a log.

> This makes sense, but doesn't it slow down to write every operation to a log server rather than in batch (because it is written to a disk)?

The distributed file system behind Bigtable (formerly [Google File System](http://research.google.com/archive/gfs.html), now [Colossus](http://www.wired.com/2012/07/google-colossus/)) is much faster than typical file systems, even though it's distributed and each write is replicated.

On benchmarks using [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB), Google Cloud Bigtable has demonstrated [single-digit millisecond latency](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/05/introducing-Google-Cloud-Bigtable.html) on both reads and writes even at the tail:

[image: Google Cloud Bigtable performance: throughput and latency]